# Cancel previous Jenkins job builds only if it's the same branch

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

I have the following code to cancel a previous job build if a new one is started:

```
def cancelPreviousBuilds() {
    def jobName = env.JOB_NAME 
    def buildNumber = env.BUILD_NUMBER.toInteger() /* Get job name */ def currentJob = 
    Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(jobName)

    for (def build : currentJob.builds) {
        
        if (build.isBuilding() && build.number.toInteger() != buildNumber) {        
           build.doStop()
    }
  }
}
```

However, I would like this to not cancel previous job builds if it's a different branch. For instance, if a job build on `develop` were kicked off and then another one on `master`, it would not cancel any job builds.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the build parameters of each build and compare the relevant values.
You can use `build.getAction(hudson.model.ParametersAction)` to get the [ParametersAction](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/ParametersAction.html) object from where you can search for parameters in the build object using the [getParameter](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/ParametersAction.html#getParameter-java.lang.String-) function.
Something like:

```
@NonCPS
def cancelPreviousBuilds() {
    def buildNumber = env.BUILD_NUMBER.toInteger()
    def currentJob = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(env.JOB_NAME)
    def currentBranch = <BRANCH_PARAM_NAME> // Branch value of the current build

    for (def build : currentJob.builds) {
        def param = build.getAction(hudson.model.ParametersAction).getParameter('<BRANCH_PARAM_NAME>')
        if (build.isBuilding() && build.number.toInteger() > buildNumber && currentBranch == param.value) {
            build.doStop()
        }
    }
```

Another small thing, in the build number comparison it is better to use `build.number.toInteger() > buildNumber` then `build.number.toInteger() != buildNumber` to prevent the case in which old builds cancel new started builds, as you usually want each build to affect only previous ones.